# SQL Not Null contraint on entire table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, ddl

I was wondering if there is any way to make a single Not Null constraint that could apply to all the attributes in my table. I know I could add one to each line, but I am just trying to learn to be more efficient. I tried searching online and I didn't find anything on this topic.

Thanks!

**MORE INFO:**

I guess my question could be generalized to ask "Is there any way to define table-wide or database-wide constraints?". For this entire database, I need to the default value of every varchar to '' (the empty string) but right now I am doing that manually for every varchar.

Again, I already did most of it, but it seems like there should be a way to avoid this repetition.

Comment: Some DBMS support DOMAINs (aka "user defined data types") where you can put such restriction into a central place. But MySQL doesn't. So you either need to stick with repeating this information for each column or think about migrating e.g. to PostgreSQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html - the only place you can put a null/not null is on a column.

```
column_definition:
    data_type [NOT NULL | NULL] [DEFAULT default_value]
      [AUTO_INCREMENT] [UNIQUE [KEY] | [PRIMARY] KEY]
      [COMMENT 'string']
      [COLUMN_FORMAT {FIXED|DYNAMIC|DEFAULT}]
      [STORAGE {DISK|MEMORY|DEFAULT}]
      [reference_definition]
```

There's really no reason to have a table constraint, IMO.  The DDL specifies constrains on the data in each column, not the column definition itself.  While one might want to put this in as syntactic sugar, it seems like there could be disadvantages - 1) to add a new column you might have to alter the table constraint 2) MySQL defaults to NULL and this might lead to confusion

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for but I guess it is what it is. I meant the result, not your advice btw

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't any way to do this. You have to speciy this at the column level but this is something you only do once. Perhaps is a couple of keystrokes more or one click per column. No inefficiency there.

Comment: I get that its not too much work, and I probably spent more time asking the question then I did doing the work - but thats not my purpose of asking. I was hoping there would be a better way, thats all.

Comment: @hbtest I understand, yours is a valid question specially after you edited it. BTW: I wouldn't use empty string to represent the absence of a value. NULL fits better that purpose.

Comment: Requirement given to me, not my choice

Comment: @lcarus sorry, I know you gave the same answer, but spinning_plate showed me why.

Comment: @hbtest As we say in Spanish: "Al César lo que es del César". No need to apologize, his answer is better. I upvoted it too.

Answer (score 0):

Have you think in `triggers` or `stored procedures`? It totally depends on your DBMS. But it also adds a over work in the DB.

Forget about the `CHECK` clause because `mySql` ignores it.

Comment: Could you explain multi column constraints? (I know I could look them up, but I think it adds to completeness of question to have it here for other people looking at it)

Comment: @UdoFholl: Actually almost all DBMS do support CHECK constraints. AFAIK MySQL and probably SQLite are the *only* ones that doe not support them.